# How to install minergate-cli in centos 6.6

Tags: centos

[image]

How to install minergate-cli in centos 6.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, it is necessary install the missing dependencies, in my case I have installed the epel repository too:

```
~$ sudo yum install -y libXrender mtdev libproxy xcb-util-wm xcb-util-image xcb-util-keysyms mesa-libEGL mesa-libGL compat-libxcb
```

or

```
~# yum install -y libXrender mtdev libproxy xcb-util-wm xcb-util-image xcb-util-keysyms mesa-libEGL mesa-libGL compat-libxcb
```