# Error on Centos Minergate Installation

Tags: miner-configuration, centos

I am new to mining and starting with installing minergate in my server which most of the time sits hosting. I figured I have some resource left over and installing minergate to dedicate 2 cores to it.

I have followed these:
https://jonathansblog.co.uk/mining-altcoins-in-centos
[How to install minergate-cli in centos 6.6](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/54045/how-to-install-minergate-cli-in-centos-6-6)
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220503/how-to-install-dependencies-of-an-rpm-package-without-installing-the-package-its

But I am still getting this error:

```
[~]# sudo yum install -y minergate.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Examining minergate.rpm: minergate-cli-6.2_gcc4-1.x86_64
Marking minergate.rpm to be installed
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 66.23.237.210
 * base: mirrors.umflint.edu
 * epel: ftp.cse.buffalo.edu
 * extras: centos.mirror.constant.com
 * updates: mirror.lug.udel.edu
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package minergate-cli.x86_64 0:6.2_gcc4-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) for package: minergate-cli-6.2_gcc4-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit) for package: minergate-cli-6.2_gcc4-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit) for package: minergate-cli-6.2_gcc4-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.18)(64bit) for package: minergate-cli-6.2_gcc4-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre16.so.0()(64bit) for package: minergate-cli-6.2_gcc4-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libproxy.so.1()(64bit) for package: minergate-cli-6.2_gcc4-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libudev.so.1()(64bit) for package: minergate-cli-6.2_gcc4-1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: minergate-cli-6.2_gcc4-1.x86_64 (/minergate)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: minergate-cli-6.2_gcc4-1.x86_64 (/minergate)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: minergate-cli-6.2_gcc4-1.x86_64 (/minergate)
           Requires: libproxy.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: minergate-cli-6.2_gcc4-1.x86_64 (/minergate)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)
Error: Package: minergate-cli-6.2_gcc4-1.x86_64 (/minergate)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.18)(64bit)
Error: Package: minergate-cli-6.2_gcc4-1.x86_64 (/minergate)
           Requires: libpcre16.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: minergate-cli-6.2_gcc4-1.x86_64 (/minergate)
           Requires: libudev.so.1()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Can anyone please help?

Thank you so much in advance.